# HttpsURLConnection authenticating twice?

Tags: java, http, ssl

I establish a secure http connection and attempt to get the `InputStream` from it afterwards. The connection occurs, and I am able to get the data, but I am actually sending two authorization requests to the server??  Here is my code that is getting the connection and getting the input stream established:

```
someConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
String userPass = username + ":" + password;
String basicAuth = "Basic" + new String(new Base64().encode(userPass.getBytes()));
someConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);            
if (header != null) someConnection.setRequestProperty(header, headerValue);
InputStream is = someConnection.getInputStream();
```

There is no traffic until the `.getInputStream()` method is called. Then I see two requests for authorization:

[image: Wireshark output]

Any ideas why it is doing that? the first request appears to be failing for some reason.

Comment: Try to add a space after `Basic`, by replacing `"Basic"` with `"Basic "`

Comment: Adding the space did solve the issue, but I would like to point out that without the space, the second time ALWAYS authenticated correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of your header `Authorization` doesn't match with the expected format, it should be `"Basic "` followed by `${username}:${password}` encoded with `RFC2045-MIME` variant of Base 64 (more details about [Basic access authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)).

Here you forgot to add the trailing space after `Basic` such that authentication is never done properly which leads to this unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

There should be space between "Basic" and the base64 encoded data.

Without this the Authorization header is wrong. I would guess that you receive 401 on the first request and send the next with other credentials possibly obtained from different source (JAAS?).